# Why does rake db:rollback rollback three steps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rollback

Normally when I do

```
$ rake db:rollback
```

it rolls back one migration. But now, repeatedly times, it has rollbacked 3 steps.

**How come this behaviour?**

I'm on Rails 3.2.13.

Comment: No, I rolled back once (with the stated command), and it rolled back not only one (expected step) but three.

Comment: Can you display a list of your migrations?

Answer (score 80):

You can specify the number of steps like this:

```
rake db:rollback STEP=3
```

The `STEP` parameter is actually an environment variable here. If, in your terminal, you run the command `echo $STEP`, does it return 3? If it does, you can execute `export STEP=1` to get back to expected behaviour. If it happens again, try to find out where this environment variable is being set.